# Jquery Table Sorter Date Extraction with Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am trying to use Jquery Table sorter plugin latest available.  http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#Demo

The issue is I have a table column with Date format and also it contains an email value. I am trying to extract the date value and sort it based on date value.

Since I am using latest version of Table sorter I tried to use the parser class name available in the latest(http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html) .

Please find my fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/pztqe/8/

Code Snippet:

```
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Major</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>English</th>
        <th>Japanese</th>
        <th>Calculus</th>
        <th>Geometry</th>
        <th class="sorter-shortDate">Date</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Student01</td>
        <td>Languages</td>
        <td>male</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>75</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td><em>11/01/12 11:42</em><spanclass="label">xyz@xyz.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#table-Id').tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            dateFormat : "ddmmyy",
            textExtraction: {
                7: function(node, table, cellIndex) {
                    return $(node).find("em").text();
                }
            }
        });


});


</script>
```

Comment: You can set the date in format Year/month/day... It will be a quick fix, but not the best

Comment: Thanks mike but in my case I could use the above format or US long format only.I want the sorting to work based on that.

Comment: You can start by separing the email and the date, it will be a better start ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there should be a space between the span and class.

Second, the date parser is only set up to work with 4-digit years `ddmmyyyy`. See [this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/150#issuecomment-9341527) to get a parser that works with 2-digit years, but please read everything to see how IE behaves with 2-digit years.

```
<td><em>11/01/2012 11:42</em><span class="label">xyz@xyz.com</span></td>
```

Third, because of the content of the date column, you'll need to set the sorter option in the header:

```
headers: {
    7: { sorter: 'shortDate' }
}
```

And lastly, there were two `textExtraction` options in the demo. The second one, not the one you posted above, was overriding the function. The one you wrote works perfectly :)

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pztqe/10/) of the above mentioned changes.

---

Update: Here's an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/25/) using the following parser code:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "ddmmyy",
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        s = s
            // replace separators
            .replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/[\-|\.|\,]/g, "/")
            // reformat dd/mm/yy to mm/dd/yy
            .replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{2})/, "$2/$1/$3");
        var d = new Date(s), y = d.getFullYear();
        // if date > 50 years old, add 100 years
        // this will work when people start using "70" and mean "2070"
        if (new Date().getFullYear() - y > 50) {
            d.setFullYear( y + 100 );
        }
        return d.getTime();
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mottie for the brilliant tool(Tablesorter) and for this answer.

Comment: Check out the updated demo I added... it only works with the "ddmmyy" format, but if you want it to work with "mmddyy" then just change the order of the replace to `"$1/$2/$3"`; and rename the parser to "mmddyy" of course ;)